# C, TCP, recvAll block is not receing anything

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, recv

I am new to both C and socket programming, so please bear with me. The following code is mostly from Beej networking guide, with some changes. I have the receiver code attached (which is TCP server in this case), that listens to multiple TCP connections.  I have a transmitter (client) who is constantly sending fixed chunks of data to this receiver.  This code (which I cleaned and removed some function definitions unrelated to my issue) works if instead of calling recv_all function, I only call recv().  But the problem with that I need to do processing on each chunk of received data, so I need the whole chunk.  So I thought I should use the recv_all().

Now the problem is it gets stuck in an infinite loop in the while in recv_all(), because n is always 0. I truly appreciate your help.

```
#define PORT "3490"  // the port users will be connecting to
#define BACKLOG 20     // how many pending connections queue will hold
#define MAXDATASIZE 801 // max number of bytes we can get at once 

int recv_all(int socket, char *buffer, int *length)
{
    int total = 0;        // how many bytes we've sent
    int bytesleft = *length; // how many we have left to send
    int n;

    while(total < *length) {

        n = recv(socket, buffer+total, bytesleft, 0);
        if (n == -1) { break; }
        total += n;
        bytesleft -= n;
    }
    *length = total; // return number actually received here

    return n==-1?-1:0; // return -1 on failure, 0 on success
}

int main(void)
{
    int sockfd, new_fd;  // listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_fd
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr; // connector's address information
    socklen_t sin_size;
    struct sigaction sa;
    int yes=1;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int rv;
    double buf[MAXDATASIZE];
    int lenRecv;

    struct sockaddr_in local_addr;      // For the new addition to bind it to an interface

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // use my IP

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    // loop through all the results and bind to the first we can
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("server: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
            perror("setsockopt");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("server: bind");
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure

    if (listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler; // reap all dead processes
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("server: waiting for connections...\n");

    while(1) {  // main accept() loop
        sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
        new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
        if (new_fd == -1) {
            perror("accept");
            continue;
        }

        inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr), s, sizeof s);
        printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);

        if (!fork()) { // this is the child process
            close(sockfd); // child doesn't need the listener

            for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
                int rowInfoSize;
                //if ((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, sizeof (buf), 0)) == -1) {
                //if ((numbytes = recv(new_fd, buf, sizeof (buf), MSG_WAITALL)) == -1) {        // I THINK THE BETTER WAY IS to CHECK THE OUTPUT AND LOOP UNTIL COMPLETE.               

                lenRecv = sizeof (buf);
                //if (recv_all(new_fd, (char *)buf, &lenRecv) == -1) {
                if (recv_all(new_fd, buf, &lenRecv) == -1) {
                    perror("sendall");
                    printf("We only sent %d bytes because of the error!\n", lenRecv);
                } 
            }   
            close(new_fd);
            exit(0);
        }
        close(new_fd);  // parent doesn't need this
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So are your chunks exactly 801 bytes long in every case? The purpose of `recv_all` is to receive a specific number of bytes. If your data is smaller than that, you'll get stuck waiting for more.

Comment: Well, what happens when you put a breakpoint on, say, 'bytesleft -= n;' and then inspect the values of n, total and bytesleft as the code loops round the recv()?

Comment: Now would be a good time to use the debugger.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the infinite loop is because n is always 0.

Comment: ^^^^^^^^^ Aaaaarrggghhhhhhhhhhh!

Comment: ... and what do you think that means?

Comment: @ThingyWotsit   my question is basically why I have this problem with recv_all(), but not when using only recv()? why output of recv in recv_all function is always 0, but not when I am only using recv()?

Comment: @Ari Because your recv_all() function does not handle the case when recv() returns 0 (which means the client has disconnected).. You need to add code to handle that just like you did when recv() returns -1

Comment: @binary01  Okay, I get that I should add handling of return value of 0 for recv().  But why in recv_all() I am having this issue, and it never happens when I am NOT using recv_all, but just using recv()?  So my guess is something else is also going wrong.

Comment: @Ari The recv() function is a standard function that is not buggy. The recv_all() function that you posted has bugs, that is why you have issues with it. It tries to receive as many bytes as you pass in to it, and then it all goes sideways and goes bonkers if the client disconnects before it sent as much data as you're trying to read. While just calling recv() does not have such a flaw.

Comment: @binary01 Sorry I am not sure why I am not clear:  my question is why when using recv_all()  I am suddenly having problem with client connection, but that is not the case when I don't call the recv_all() function.  (when I only call recv(), I can see that I get almost all the data, so client connection should not be an issue.)

Comment: @Ari And I don't understand why you don't understand that using a recv_all() function that is broken, buggy and does not work, is causing you issues. Can you try to rephrase what you don't understand ? Do you understand what your recv_all() function does and why it can go  into an infinite loop ? Do you understand that the standard recv() function does not go into such an infinite loop and therefore does not cause you this issue  ?

Comment: @binary01 yes I understand why recv() does not go into an infinite loop but my recv_all() can.  What I don't understand is why in my recv_all() function, right at the beginning, the output of recv() is 0, which causes this infinite loop since I am not taking care 0 case.  I added a condition to break out of the loop if recv() output is 0, and it solved the infinite loop issue.  But still my question remains unanswered for me.

Comment: @binary01 Never mind.  I was wrong the whole time that my code was getting stuck right at the beginning, which confused me that something else is going wrong.  It was just stuck at the end when client is done sending. So now everything makes sense.   Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are ignoring end of stream. If `n == 0` the peer has disconnected. Your code will loop forever.

Throw it all away and use `recv()` with the `MSG_WAITALL` option.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the infinite loop is because of n=0.  But my question is why? Why I don't have this problem when using recv(), but only when using recv_all() function?

Comment: Because, obviously, `recv()` does not loop forever at end of stream, unlike your buggy code.

Comment: I just noticed you mentioned "using `recv()` with the `MSG_WAITALL` option".  Are they identical?  I was actually using the `MSG_WAITALL` option before, and it looked like it was working fine but I wasn't sure of its overhead and also hadn't seen ANY sample code that mentioned using that option instead of writing their own recv_all.  I am glad you mentioned it.

Comment: The MSG_WAITALL option does exactly what you want. You can't seriously suggest that a single system call has more overhead than a buggy piece of code in user space that calls multiple system calls and smokes the CPU when it fails. Even when you remove the bugs it isn't a plausible suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

give recv_all a timeout value

```
int recv_all(int socket, char *buffer, int *length, int timeout)
```

and use select before recv()

```
int select(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds, fd_set *exceptfds, struct timeval *timeout);
```

> 

looks like this

```
int recv_all(int socket, char *buffer, int *length)
{
    int total = 0;        // how many bytes we've sent
    int bytesleft = *length; // how many we have left to send
    int n = -1;

    struct timeval timeout;
    fd_set rset;
    int rc;

    timeout.tv_sec = 1;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    while(total < *length) {

        FD_ZERO(&rset);
        FD_SET(socket, &rset);
        rc = select(socket + 1, &rset, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
        if(rc < 0)
        {
            // errno
            n = -1;
            break;
        }

        if(0 == rc)
        {
            // timeout
            n = -1;
            break;
        }

        if(FD_ISSET(socket, &rset))
        {
            n = recv(socket, buffer+total, bytesleft, 0);
            if (n == -1) { break; }
            total += n;
            bytesleft -= n;
            timeout.tv_sec = 1;
            timeout.tv_usec = 0;
        }
    }

    *length = total; // return number actually received here

    return n==-1?-1:0; // return -1 on failure, 0 on success
}
```

Comment: Could you explain a little more please?

Comment: Could you explain how this answers the question? And identifies and fixes the problem with the OP's code? And how all this is superior to settting a read timeout in one line of code with `SO_RCVTIMEO`?

Comment: Thanks for your time.  I will try this later too.  My original problem is solved though. It is in the comments below my original question.

Comment: @Ari Don't. It has nothing to do  with your problem, and in fact it merely repeats it.

Comment: And it doesn't even give `recv_all()` a timeout parameter as suggested in the first paragraph.